# Parent element becoming transparent in the portion of it covered by the child element. Possible?

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I'm trying to make an hover effect in which the parent element, such as a nav element, becomes transparent only in the portion of it covered by the child element. This way i could see the background image that's set on the main container of the site. Is there a pure css solution or should i use javascript (jquery) to achieve such an effect? Or, is it even possible?

Starting point http://jsfiddle.net/gBsEA/4/

```
<div id="container">
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Thank</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">You</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Very</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Much</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: you can set opacity property on hover

Comment: Could you provide a wireframe or jsfiddle?

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/XFbNH/ ?

Comment: @dfsq no, see my fiddle it's something different. In your example the black area should become transparent only in the area of the hovered link

Comment: When you say "area of the hovered link", are you talking about the `<li>` tag? also, please add the `<a>` tags in your fiddle.

Comment: @MarcAudet Yes, sorry, maybe i was uncler. I was referring to the exemple posted by dfsq when i said "area of the hovered link". I update it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjusting the opacity will not work.  However, you can do a trick with the background image:

```
#container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background: url(http://www.dj-photo.com/files/2813/5912/7137/chilli-abstract_500px.jpg) no-repeat fixed 0 -40px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
nav {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #e9e9e9;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
nav li:hover {
    background: url(http://www.dj-photo.com/files/2813/5912/7137/chilli-abstract_500px.jpg) no-repeat fixed 0 -40px;
}
```

In this case, you simply repeat the `background` to the hovering element.  If you use the `fixed` value, you don't have to repeat it on every element.

Fiddle reference: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/x5e2C/

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, you cannot set opacity on just a portion of an element with CSS alone. Also, in this case you'd need to affect an ancestral element, which is also impossible.

One potential solution would be to set the same background image on the LI:hover, and position it appropriately so as to make it appear as though you're seeing the ancestor element's background.

http://jsfiddle.net/gBsEA/7

```
nav li.three:hover {
    background: url(myfile.jpg) no-repeat -280px -100px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Feel free. I don't think it'll be easy. You'll probably need to do a bunch of calculation. Fiddle updated.

Comment: I really can't find nothing already done. I mean, someone should have thought of that before. Your example is really clear and perfect for a static solution but i have a multilungual site and it would be hard to set the backgrounds for all the languages.

Comment: In my opinion it would be easier to calculate the positions of each LI and set the background position on those than to somehow cut out the opacity of the parent background. If you set the parent background position to 'top left' it would be fairly simple to get the offset of the LI elements and use that to set their hover background positions.

Comment: No math required! see my variation on the background image trick.